# HsqlDb percentile_cont/median

Tags: sql, postgresql, hsqldb

I am trying to query HSQL DB with percentile cont. Something like:

```
SELECT name, percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY measurement_value)...
```

But it seems to me that HSQLDB just has the keyword, but not he implementation. In docs there is the keyword mentioned, but nowhere else except reserved words. And when I run the query, I get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PERCENTILE_CONT
```

My motivation is to have one query calculating median, both executable in HSQLDB (for testing) and the exactly same query for Postgres (which does not have median aggregate)...

Do you know about any query, which would calculate median in both databases, or do I need to create a custom aggregate function in Postgres?

Thanks

(I am using latest HSQLDB 2.3.4)